# How to handle authentication with TIdHTTP

Tags: c++builder, indy10

I'm using C++Builder XE6 and `TIdHTTP` to communicate with a REST server in a Windows application.
I need some advice on how to handle authentication.

Given the following code:

```
#include <IdHTTP.hpp>
#include <IdAuthenticationDigest.hpp>

HTTP = new TIdHTTP(NULL);

HTTP->Request->Username = Username;
HTTP->Request->Password = Password;
HTTP->Request->BasicAuthentication = UseBasicAuthentication;
HTTP->OnAuthorization = AuthRequired;
```

The variables `Username` (string), `Password` (string) and `UseBasicAuthentication` (bool) are user-configurable parameters.

I don't know in advance if the REST server requires authentication or not, nor which type of authentication it supports (Basic or Digest).

AFAIK, the `Username` and `Password` members of `TIdHTTPRequest` are used in the first try to authenticate with the server.
If the initial authentication fails, the OnAuthorization event handler is triggered to obtain new credentials.

Does `TIdHTTP` only supply the credentials in response to a 401 response code from the server, or are they always included in the request?

Also, is there a standard dialog box that can be used to prompt the user for credentials?

**Update**

Also need to set the following:

```
HTTP->HTTPOptions = HTTP->HTTPOptions << hoInProcessAuth;
```

**Update 2**

[CredUIPromptForCredentials()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincred/nf-wincred-creduipromptforcredentialsa) can be used to show a credentials dialog box on Windows:

```
#include <wincred.h>

CREDUI_INFO cui;

cui.cbSize         = sizeof(cui);
cui.hwndParent     = NULL;
cui.pszMessageText = _T("Your message here");
cui.pszCaptionText = Application->Title.c_str();
cui.hbmBanner      = NULL;

TCHAR pszUsername[CREDUI_MAX_USERNAME_LENGTH + 1] = _T("Username");
TCHAR pszPassword[CREDUI_MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH + 1] = _T("Password");
BOOL fSave = false;

if (CredUIPromptForCredentials(&cui, _T("https://www.stackoverflow.com"), NULL, 0, pszUsername, ARRAYSIZE(pszUsername), pszPassword, ARRAYSIZE(pszPassword), &fSave, CREDUI_FLAGS_DO_NOT_PERSIST | CREDUI_FLAGS_SHOW_SAVE_CHECK_BOX | CREDUI_FLAGS_ALWAYS_SHOW_UI | CREDUI_FLAGS_GENERIC_CREDENTIALS) == NO_ERROR)
    ...
```

The `pszUsername` and `pszPassword` parameters return the entered credentials as plaintext.
The state of the 'Remember my credentials' checkbox is returned in the `fSave` parameter.

**Update 3**

I tried the following to test Basic Authentication:

```
#include <IdHTTP.hpp>
#include <IdAllAuthentications.hpp>

void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    TIdHTTP* HTTP = new TIdHTTP(NULL);

    try
    {
        HTTP->HTTPOptions = HTTP->HTTPOptions << hoInProcessAuth << hoNoProtocolErrorException;
        HTTP->Request->BasicAuthentication = false;
        HTTP->MaxAuthRetries = 10;
        HTTP->OnAuthorization = AuthRequired;

        HTTP->Get("http://httpbin.org/basic-auth/user/pass");

        Memo->Lines->Add(IntToStr(HTTP->ResponseCode));
    }
    __finally
    {
        delete HTTP;
    }
}

void __fastcall TForm1::AuthRequired (TObject *Sender, TIdAuthentication *Authentication, bool &Handled)
{
    TIdHTTP* HTTP = dynamic_cast<TIdHTTP*>(Sender);

    String Username = Authentication->Username;
    String Password = Authentication->Password;

    String Server = HTTP->URL->Protocol + "://" + HTTP->URL->Host;

    Handled = PromptForCredentials(Application->Title, "Enter credentials for " + Server + ".", Server, Username, Password);

    Authentication->Username = Username;
    Authentication->Password = Password;
}
```

I wrapped the code in **Update 2** in a function called `PromptForCredentials()`, which returns `true` when the user chose OK.

`TIdHTTP` triggers the `OnAuthorization` event only once.
If I enter the correct credentials, I get a 200 response, which is correct.
If I enter incorrect credentials, I get a 401 response without triggering the `OnAuthorization` event again.

After the `HTTP->Get()` call, the value of `HTTP->Request->BasicAuthentication` changed to `true`, which is correct.

Shouldn't `TIdHTTP` keep triggering `OnAuthorization` until either a 200 response, `Handled` is set to `false` or `HTTP->MaxAuthRetries` is reached?

PS: My Indy version is 10.6.0.5122.

**Update 4**

To test Digest Authentication, I changed the following line in the code listed under **Update 3**:

```
HTTP->Get("http://httpbin.org/digest-auth/auth/user/pass");
```

`OnAuthorization` is also triggered only once. This time, `HTTP->Request->BasicAuthentication` remains `false`, which is correct.

**Update 5**

I've set `HTTP->MaxAuthRetries = 3` and added file logging:

```
HTTP->Intercept = new TIdLogFile(HTTP);
static_cast<TIdLogFile*>(HTTP->Intercept)->Filename = "Project1.log";
static_cast<TIdLogFile*>(HTTP->Intercept)->Active = true;
```

If I enter incorrect credentials (Username = `test`, Password = `test`) in the dialog box when `OnAuthorization` is triggered, the logs show that `TIdHTTP` replies to the 401 response 3 times with the same credentials. The `OnAuthorization` is not triggered again after the first one, for both Basic Autentication and Digest Authentication.

The log for Basic Authentication:

```
Stat Connected.
Sent 31-03-2022 08:58:55: GET /basic-auth/user/pass HTTP/1.1<EOL>Host: httpbin.org<EOL>Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8<EOL>Accept-Encoding: identity<EOL>User-Agent: Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)<EOL><EOL>
Recv 31-03-2022 08:58:55: HTTP/1.1 401 UNAUTHORIZED<EOL>Date: Thu, 31 Mar 2022 06:58:55 GMT<EOL>Content-Length: 0<EOL>Connection: keep-alive<EOL>Server: gunicorn/19.9.0<EOL>WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Fake Realm"<EOL>Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *<EOL>Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true<EOL><EOL>
Sent 31-03-2022 08:59:03: GET /basic-auth/user/pass HTTP/1.1<EOL>Host: httpbin.org<EOL>Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8<EOL>Accept-Encoding: identity<EOL>User-Agent: Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)<EOL>Authorization: Basic dGVzdDp0ZXN0<EOL><EOL>
Recv 31-03-2022 08:59:03: HTTP/1.1 401 UNAUTHORIZED<EOL>Date: Thu, 31 Mar 2022 06:59:03 GMT<EOL>Content-Length: 0<EOL>Connection: keep-alive<EOL>Server: gunicorn/19.9.0<EOL>WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Fake Realm"<EOL>Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *<EOL>Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true<EOL><EOL>
Sent 31-03-2022 08:59:03: GET /basic-auth/user/pass HTTP/1.1<EOL>Host: httpbin.org<EOL>Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8<EOL>Accept-Encoding: identity<EOL>User-Agent: Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)<EOL>Authorization: Basic dGVzdDp0ZXN0<EOL><EOL>
Recv 31-03-2022 08:59:03: HTTP/1.1 401 UNAUTHORIZED<EOL>Date: Thu, 31 Mar 2022 06:59:03 GMT<EOL>Content-Length: 0<EOL>Connection: keep-alive<EOL>Server: gunicorn/19.9.0<EOL>WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Fake Realm"<EOL>Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *<EOL>Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true<EOL><EOL>
Sent 31-03-2022 08:59:03: GET /basic-auth/user/pass HTTP/1.1<EOL>Host: httpbin.org<EOL>Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8<EOL>Accept-Encoding: identity<EOL>User-Agent: Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)<EOL>Authorization: Basic dGVzdDp0ZXN0<EOL><EOL>
Recv 31-03-2022 08:59:03: HTTP/1.1 401 UNAUTHORIZED<EOL>Date: Thu, 31 Mar 2022 06:59:03 GMT<EOL>Content-Length: 0<EOL>Connection: keep-alive<EOL>Server: gunicorn/19.9.0<EOL>WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Fake Realm"<EOL>Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *<EOL>Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true<EOL><EOL>
Stat Disconnected.
Stat Disconnected.
```

Note that `dGVzdDp0ZXN0` (Base64) decodes to `test:test`.

The log for Digest Authentication:

```
Stat Connected.
Sent 31-03-2022 09:28:41: GET /digest-auth/auth/user/pass HTTP/1.1<EOL>Host: httpbin.org<EOL>Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8<EOL>Accept-Encoding: identity<EOL>User-Agent: Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)<EOL><EOL>
Recv 31-03-2022 09:28:41: HTTP/1.1 401 UNAUTHORIZED<EOL>Date: Thu, 31 Mar 2022 07:28:41 GMT<EOL>Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8<EOL>Content-Length: 0<EOL>Connection: keep-alive<EOL>Server: gunicorn/19.9.0<EOL>WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="me@kennethreitz.com", nonce="83f09ed264f5704d1cfc630d90b3091d", qop="auth", opaque="d075bef19d3e723ddf38e585e4c15142", algorithm=MD5, stale=FALSE<EOL>Set-Cookie: stale_after=never; Path=/<EOL>Set-Cookie: fake=fake_value; Path=/<EOL>Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *<EOL>Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true<EOL><EOL>
Sent 31-03-2022 09:28:46: GET /digest-auth/auth/user/pass HTTP/1.1<EOL>Host: httpbin.org<EOL>Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8<EOL>Accept-Encoding: identity<EOL>User-Agent: Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)<EOL>Authorization: Digest username="test", realm="me@kennethreitz.com", nonce="83f09ed264f5704d1cfc630d90b3091d", algorithm="MD5", uri="/digest-auth/auth/user/pass", qop="auth", nc=00000001, cnonce="f73bb234744d902a6909b0d511c6eab4", response="a7e13d327c9c13a446413530cfc44fc9", opaque="d075bef19d3e723ddf38e585e4c15142"<EOL>Cookie: fake=fake_value; stale_after=never<EOL><EOL>
Recv 31-03-2022 09:28:47: HTTP/1.1 401 UNAUTHORIZED<EOL>Date: Thu, 31 Mar 2022 07:28:47 GMT<EOL>Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8<EOL>Content-Length: 0<EOL>Connection: keep-alive<EOL>Server: gunicorn/19.9.0<EOL>WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="me@kennethreitz.com", nonce="be0945b8e925b386b3f493058d757aeb", qop="auth", opaque="f0301998fadceaf2d562e3b4934da438", algorithm=MD5, stale=FALSE<EOL>Set-Cookie: stale_after=never; Path=/<EOL>Set-Cookie: last_nonce=83f09ed264f5704d1cfc630d90b3091d; Path=/<EOL>Set-Cookie: fake=fake_value; Path=/<EOL>Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *<EOL>Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true<EOL><EOL>
Sent 31-03-2022 09:28:47: GET /digest-auth/auth/user/pass HTTP/1.1<EOL>Host: httpbin.org<EOL>Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8<EOL>Accept-Encoding: identity<EOL>User-Agent: Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)<EOL>Authorization: Digest username="test", realm="me@kennethreitz.com", nonce="be0945b8e925b386b3f493058d757aeb", algorithm="MD5", uri="/digest-auth/auth/user/pass", qop="auth", nc=00000001, cnonce="fe65a7188cc197c3ee68c1e2840bab9a", response="2cfce7fc3c9099430841cab1b10eb706", opaque="f0301998fadceaf2d562e3b4934da438"<EOL>Cookie: fake=fake_value; stale_after=never; last_nonce=83f09ed264f5704d1cfc630d90b3091d<EOL><EOL>
Recv 31-03-2022 09:28:47: HTTP/1.1 401 UNAUTHORIZED<EOL>Date: Thu, 31 Mar 2022 07:28:47 GMT<EOL>Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8<EOL>Content-Length: 0<EOL>Connection: keep-alive<EOL>Server: gunicorn/19.9.0<EOL>WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="me@kennethreitz.com", nonce="6cffc5d099ca89fffc766509726ecd1e", qop="auth", opaque="dea9f785474babae87a69b120be54038", algorithm=MD5, stale=FALSE<EOL>Set-Cookie: stale_after=never; Path=/<EOL>Set-Cookie: last_nonce=be0945b8e925b386b3f493058d757aeb; Path=/<EOL>Set-Cookie: fake=fake_value; Path=/<EOL>Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *<EOL>Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true<EOL><EOL>
Sent 31-03-2022 09:28:47: GET /digest-auth/auth/user/pass HTTP/1.1<EOL>Host: httpbin.org<EOL>Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8<EOL>Accept-Encoding: identity<EOL>User-Agent: Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)<EOL>Authorization: Digest username="test", realm="me@kennethreitz.com", nonce="6cffc5d099ca89fffc766509726ecd1e", algorithm="MD5", uri="/digest-auth/auth/user/pass", qop="auth", nc=00000001, cnonce="fe65a7188cc197c3ee68c1e2840bab9a", response="e425bf56ca44430aa8f864fb9e4b10a7", opaque="dea9f785474babae87a69b120be54038"<EOL>Cookie: fake=fake_value; stale_after=never; last_nonce=be0945b8e925b386b3f493058d757aeb<EOL><EOL>
Recv 31-03-2022 09:28:47: HTTP/1.1 401 UNAUTHORIZED<EOL>Date: Thu, 31 Mar 2022 07:28:47 GMT<EOL>Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8<EOL>Content-Length: 0<EOL>Connection: keep-alive<EOL>Server: gunicorn/19.9.0<EOL>WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="me@kennethreitz.com", nonce="b448581a59e0fec2df8f3f9f8340721b", qop="auth", opaque="049d8958d842b80beee17b21d04e5b7e", algorithm=MD5, stale=FALSE<EOL>Set-Cookie: stale_after=never; Path=/<EOL>Set-Cookie: last_nonce=6cffc5d099ca89fffc766509726ecd1e; Path=/<EOL>Set-Cookie: fake=fake_value; Path=/<EOL>Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *<EOL>Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true<EOL><EOL>
Stat Disconnected.
Stat Disconnected.
```

If I set `HTTP->Request->Username = "test"` and `HTTP->Request->Password = "test"` prior to the call to `HTTP->Get(...)`, the `OnAuthorization` event handler is never triggered and the logs also show that `TIdHTTP` retries 3 times with the incorrect credentials.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know in advance if the REST server requires authentication or not, nor which type of authentication it supports (Basic or Digest).

`TIdHTTP` natively supports `Basic` when `Request->Authentication` is `NULL` and `Request->BasicAuthentication` is `true`.

`TIdHTTP` also supports `Digest`, however you have to enable it manually first, by adding one of the following statements to your code:

`#include <IdAuthenticationDigest.hpp>`

`#include <IdAllAuthentications.hpp>`

(`#pragma link` is handled for you)

Internally, `TIdHTTP` will then pick the appropriate `TIdAuthentication`-derived class based on what the server asks for in a 401 response.

> AFAIK, the `Username` and `Password` members of `TIdHTTPRequest` are used in the first try to authenticate with the server. If the initial authentication fails, the `OnAuthorization` event handler is triggered to obtain new credentials.

Correct.

> Does `TIdHTTP` only supply the credentials in response to a 401 response code from the server, or are they always included in the request?

That depends.

If `Request->Authentication` is assigned a `TIdAuthentication`-derived object, it is queried for pending credentials, and if any are given then they are sent to the server.  For example, in multi-step authentications like NTLM, etc.

Otherwise, if `Request->Authentication` is `NULL` and `Request->BasicAuthentication` is `true`, `Request->Authentication` is set to `TIdBasicAuthentication`, and then `Basic` credentials are sent to the server (even if the `UserName` and `Password` are blank! See [#403](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/403) in Indy's issue tracker).

Otherwise, no credentials are sent to the server, unless you provide your own credentials in the `Request->CustomHeaders` property.

**UPDATE**

> `TIdHTTP` triggers the `OnAuthorization` event only once. If I enter the correct credentials, I get a 200 response, which is correct. If I enter incorrect credentials, I get a 401 response without triggering the `OnAuthorization` event again.

`TIdHTTP` is *supposed* to trigger the `OnAuthorization` event each time it receives a `401` response, unless either:

- `TIdHTTP.AuthRetries` reaches `TIdHTTP.MaxAuthRetries`
- the `TIdHTTP.OnSelectAuthorization` event sets the `AuthenticationClass` parameter to `nil`

However, if neither of those conditions are met, the `OnAuthorization` event is triggered only when the current `Request->Authentication` object returns `wnAskTheProgram` from its `Next()` method, which is called each time `401` is received (after the above conditions are checked).

In the case of `TIdBasicAuthentication`, its `Next()` method returns `wnAskTheProgram` only when the current `Username` is blank.  This is probably a bug that needs to be fixed (I have [opened a ticket](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/404) in Indy's issue tracker for you). The failed `Username`/`Password` *should* be reset on each `401` response. And there is actually code to that effect in `IdHTTP.pas`, but it is currently commented out because apparently it breaks multi-step authentications, like SSPI/NTLM.

> After the `HTTP->Get()` call, the value of `HTTP->Request->BasicAuthentication` changed to true, which is correct.

It really shouldn't.  But after `OnAuthorization` is triggered the 1st time, `BasicAuthentication` is hard-coded to `true`.  I don't know why that was ever added to `TIdHTTP`.

> Shouldn't `TIdHTTP` keep triggering `OnAuthorization` until either a 200 response, `Handled` is set to false or `HTTP->MaxAuthRetries` is reached?

It should, yes.

> If I enter incorrect credentials (Username = `test`, Password = `test`) in the dialog box when `OnAuthorization` is triggered, the logs show that `TIdHTTP` replies to the 401 response 3 times with the same credentials. The `OnAuthorization` is not triggered again after the first one, for both Basic Autentication and Digest Authentication.

They are both affected by the same underlying issue - that the current `Username` is not being cleared after each failed attempt.

Comment: I found a standard Windows dialog box. See the update to my original question.

Comment: See *Update 3*. My Indy version is 10.6.0.5122. How do I update to the latest version?

Comment: Please see *Update 5*. Does a newer Indy version fix this?

Comment: I have updated my answer. "*How do I update to the latest version?*" - you can download it from [GitHub](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/). You can find (archived) install instructions [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200925081341/http://ww2.indyproject.org/Sockets/Docs/Indy10Installation.EN.aspx). "*Does a newer Indy version fix this?*" - no. I have now opened a bug ticket about this.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Remy. I will try to update Indy. Your link points to the latest (stable) version?

Comment: @MartinNijhoff it points to the latest development code. [Indy doesn't have "stable releases" yet](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/328).

Comment: If I `#include <IdAllAuthentications.hpp>`, which authentication schemes are supported by TIdHTTP that don't require a client certificate? Anonymous, Basic, Digest and NTLM for sure. I'm not familiar with SSPI. Does that include Kerberos and Negotiate?

Comment: @MartinNijhoff Indy's SSPI authentication implements NTLM and Negotiate, but I don't think it implements Kerberos at this time, but I'm not sure. I was never good at understanding SSPI. In any case, `TIdHTTP`'s SSPI authentication is currently a little broken (https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/87), so I'm note sure if you would be able to use it anyway.